# jQuery Mobile Panels Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I am implementing jquery mobile panel into my site. All works fine until I decide to visit the same page twice, then the panel icon (data-icon="bars") does not open the panel. It does not respond. It works when I manually reload the page. I believe it has sth to do with the cache or ajax :-( Please help. Recap: 1. I tap the panel icon & it opens side panel. I go from page_a to page_b. Next, I go back to page_a and (data-icon="bars") does not respond anymore. I need to manually reload the page and then it works. How to fix it please? Thank you

Below you can see my code:

```
<!-- Start of page_a page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page_a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="nav-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page_a">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page_b">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page_c">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->
    </div><!-- /page_a end -->

    <!-- Start of page_b page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page_b">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        </div><!-- /content -->
        <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="nav-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page_a">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page_b">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page_c">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->
    </div><!-- /page_b end -->
```

Comment: Everything works just fine in your example. If possible create us a jsFiddle example and recreate your problem. Use this template: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/flymen8888/6v87p/ Try to go from page_a to page_b go back to page_a and try to go to page_b again. This is when you it stops working unless the page is reloaded. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same id for all panels. jQM loads pages via ajax into the existing DOM, so all your panels end up in the same DOM and jQM no longer knows which panel to open when multiple have the same ID.

> You updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6v87p/2/)**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_a">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content"><p>This is page_a.</p>
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="nav-panel">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_a">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_b">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_c">C</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /panel -->
</div><!-- /page_a end -->

<!-- Start of page_b page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page_b">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <a href="#nav-panel2" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
   <div data-role="content"><p>This is page_b.</p>
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="nav-panel2">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_a">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_b">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_c">C</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /panel -->
</div><!-- /page_b end -->

    <!-- Start of page_c page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page_c">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <a href="#nav-panel3" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content"><p>This is page_c.</p>
    </div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" id="nav-panel3">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_a">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_b">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page_c">C</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /panel -->
</div><!-- /page_c end -->
```